# Laravel with Vuejs run project without php artisan serve

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-vue

I am developing a VueJs application in Laravel. In my local environment I have to use `php artisan serve` command to serve my project. In server I am using `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000` command to run my project. I have configured apache web server.

Here my question is How should I run the project on the server without using `php artisan serve` command?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: using apache or nginx. i guess artisan serve just launches the php inbuilt dev server

Comment: Laravel has great documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x

Comment: `php artisan serve` should only be used for development purposes. For production you should use a dedicated webserver like apache or nginx.

Comment: If I have developed entirely in laravel then I could create a virtual host in apache conf file and make it as worked. But I used Vuejs as a frontend and Laravel as a backend. In this scenario How should I configure in apache web server? @Jerodev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the webpack mix file (project_root_path/webpack.mix.js) with the following

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
 .setResourceRoot("/public/");

 mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        publicPath: '/public/',
    }
 });
```

map the project folder into apache config file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf)

```
VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ProjectRoot
    Header set Cache-Control max-age=101930

    <Directory /var/www/html/ProjectRoot/public>
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

enable the port in (/etc/apache2/ports.conf). add the following line

```
Listen 8000
```

restart the apache server and check the url.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Local Development Server](https://laravel.com/docs/installation#installing-laravel)

> If you have PHP installed locally and you would like to use PHP's built-in development server to serve your application, you may use the `serve` Artisan command.

---

#### [Deployment](https://laravel.com/docs/deployment)

When you're ready to deploy your Laravel application, you should use a dedicated webserver like Apache or Nginx.

Comment: If I have developed entirely in laravel then I could create a virtual host in apache conf file and make it as worked. But I used Vuejs as a frontend and Laravel as a backend. In this scenario How should I configure in apache web server?